# Aggregation query in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am having Kibana 5.3. I have created elasticsearch bucket aggs query.

Can I execute this query from kibana to create chart?

Edit: 
I mean is there a way just to insert it somewhere? Like JSON input or external script file?
My query:

```
   {"query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "query_string": {
                "query": "XXX",
              }
            },
          ],
          "must_not": []
        }
      },
      "size": 0,
      "_source": {
        "excludes": []
      },
      "aggs": {
        "2": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "YYY",
            "size": 5,
            "order": {
              "_count": "desc"
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "3": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "ZZZ",
                "size": 5,
                "order": {
                  "_count": "desc"
                }
              },
              "aggs": {
                "4": {
                  "terms": {
                    "field": "_type",
                    "size": 5,
                    "order": {
                      "_count": "desc"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: It depends on the query you made I guess

Comment: So I can't just insert it into json input or whereever?

Comment: No, but you can do that query in Kibana selecting a visualization.